# Thread hungs , High CPU utilization

Tags: performance

We are using WAS 7 server, getting high CPU utilization. Below is SystemOut logs, Can some one help us in analyzing the cause?

```
[10/21/15 17:42:57:651 EST] 00000031 ThreadMonitor W   WSVR0605W: Thread "WebContainer : 22" (00000063) has been active for 663934 milliseconds and may be hung.  There is/are 19 thread(s) in total in the server that may be hung.
```

Comment: Who's "we"? Can you provide some more information?

Answer (score -1):

Error you provided simply means your threads are not getting cpu/ cpu time to complete their tasks.

1. Problem can be with your application i.e. some method is responsible for high cpu usage. Either its not properly written(implementation problem) or solution design(design issue) is not optimal. To find out the culprit, Profile your application with a profiler, static code analysis tools. Tune/optimize the method/code piece and then check again.
2. If all methods are not cpu heavy and design and implementations are good then it can be because of threads. Check where cpu is wasting time. Is it really busy doing useful work or just doing useless work (io, busy waiting, context switching etc.) If your application is doing unnecessary/non-useful work then try implementing thread pool / thread non-blocking queue.

Doing this also monitor your other resources (memory/network/disk) and if your application tiers like database/web/ldap etc. especially if they are deployed on same server.

I hope this will at-least help you to find a place where you need to look.